# Android - Customised New Incoming Call Screen

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an new incoming call screen in android,

when i get an incoming call my app starts - but crashes  immediately, and the default incoming call screen is coming up.

what am i doing wrong?

my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.myfirstapp"
      android:versionCode="7"
      android:versionName="7">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="10"></uses-sdk>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <receiver android:name=".MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".Call" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver.java:**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver extends Activity{

    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent main_intent = new Intent(this, Call.class);
            context.startActivity(main_intent);
    }


}
```

**Call.java:**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Call extends Activity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

}
```

the log is:

```
 10-14 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 10-14 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver
 com.example.myfirstapp.MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver:
 java.lang.ClassCastException:
 com.example.myfirstapp.MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver cannot be cast to
 android.content.BroadcastReceiver 10-14 20:59:51.056:
 E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2210)
 10-14 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:130) 10-14
 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
 10-14 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-14
 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-14 20:59:51.056:
 E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 10-14
 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-14
 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-14 20:59:51.056:
 E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 10-14 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 10-14
 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-14 20:59:51.056:
 E/AndroidRuntime(1826): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
 com.example.myfirstapp.MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver cannot be cast to
 android.content.BroadcastReceiver 10-14 20:59:51.056:
 E/AndroidRuntime(1826): at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2205)
 10-14 20:59:51.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1826): ... 10 more
```

Comment: Do you get any log output from the crash?

Comment: Shouldn't `MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver` extend `BroadcastReceiver` instead of `Activity`?

Comment: i use Activity for: Intent main_intent = new Intent(this, CallActivity.class); context.startActivity(main_intent);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, in order to make my new page in the front i need to make it sleep for a while...
so the new code will be:

```
public class MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {


        Thread pageTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(context, Call.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        pageTimer.start();
    }
}
```

**But** - the original incoming call program is still running in the background...

Is there any way to replace it instead opening new app ontop of it?

Thanks!

Comment: I've done a bit of research on this and have found a lot of posts saying this can't be done - though this app claims to do what you want (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.perracolabs.tcc).  However, the app doesn't work on my Galaxy Nexus, so it may not be something that will work on all phones.  If you found a solution to this problem, please comment back!

Comment: The above app does not replace the incoming call screen - the screenshots are for an outgoing call confirm - so I don't believe that it is possible to replace the default app, only to overlay something else on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a `ClassCastException` because your manifest defines `MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver` as a receiver, not an activity. You don't need an activity to create the intent, since it takes a `Context`, and one is provided with `onReceive()`. Have it extend `BroadcastReceiver` and alter the intent slightly like this:

```
public class MyPhoneBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent main_intent = new Intent(context, CallActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(main_intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but i got another error that i need to set "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK".  
so i changed the code to:  
Intent i = new Intent();  
i.setClass(context, Call.class);  
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
context.startActivity(i);  
Now it works, but shows up under the original incoming call screen (so i see it only after i end the call)...

Comment: I don't believe you can completely override the built-in call screen, at least up to Gingerbread. Whether it works on newer APIs I haven't been able to figure out. Just googling a bit seems to indicate it's done for security reasons. I see a lot of attempts, but most just dead end with "Oh, you can't do that". Good luck on your search, but at least you got your crash problems cleared up.

Comment: Thanks for the help! i see some apps like: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.perracolabs.tccp  and: http://code.google.com/p/incomingcallplus/ , that change this screen so it must be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest:

```
<activity> 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>  
</activity>
```

Comment: please, provide an explanation to your answer

Comment: When you add these to your manifest, it will catch the call events before the phone does