# Get current ui view android

Tags: android

In a broadcast receiver listening to `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`, call `thread.sleep` for 1 second, then start a new activity. This receiver gets called when the phone rings. 
When the code enters the new activity, the phone incoming call UI is displayed. 
Is it possible to get access to the current view of the incoming call UI, in this other activity task?

```
    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*View v = Phone UI Currently Displayed On Device*/
    }
```

Comment: can you explain what is your goal?

Comment: View v = Phone UI Currently Displayed On Device that last line. While the phone is ringing, i want that incoming call ui, and to append it.

Comment: Do you mean like a Splash Screen ?

Comment: If I am correct, you are trying to modify the incoming call screen. These links can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683841/show-the-information-in-the-middle-of-the-call and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869471/android-customised-new-incoming-call-screen

Comment: @Lucifer Not sure what about the specifics of what a splash screen is. If it takes up the whole window, then no, i want the current incoming call ui to stay there, and to append to it.

Comment: @PankajKumar Those links are just showing to start a new activity with a separate ui. I want to retrieve the one currently shown and append to it. Like: AndroidSystem.getcurrentView()

Comment: Then you mean like a progressbar or dialog will be best for  your need

Comment: Ok thanks. That still will not look as good as appending in the middle of the incoming call screen though.